# Retrieving aggregations / buckets with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

```
GET test_data/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"match": {"company":"foo"}}
  ] 
  }},

  "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
       "filenames": {
         "terms":{
           "field": "filename.keyword"
         },
        "aggs": {
         "maxDate": {"max": {"field":"timestamp"}},
         "minDate": {"min": {"field":"timestamp"}}
       }
      }     
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
{
  "took": 1052,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 52120825,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "filenames": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 97326,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 51389890,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Messages_20170711_080003.mes",
          "doc_count": 187131,
          "minDate": {
            "value": 1499724098000,
            "value_as_string": "2017-07-10T22:01:38.000Z"
          },
          "maxDate": {
            "value": 1499760002000,
            "value_as_string": "2017-07-11T08:00:02.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Messages_20170213_043108.mes",
          "doc_count": 115243,
          "minDate": {
            "value": 1486735453000,
            "value_as_string": "2017-02-10T14:04:13.000Z"
          },
          "maxDate": {
            "value": 1486960265000,
            "value_as_string": "2017-02-13T04:31:05.000Z"
          }
        },
```

This query returns the wanted result when entered in kibana dev tools.

When I try to return the result buckets with spark elasticsearch

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.esDF(esInputIndexName, query = queryString)
df.show(10, false)
```

the dataframe shows me all the hits and not the buckets with the aggregations inside.
How do I store the results provided by the aggregation / buckets in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is that you perform the aggregations via spark.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions{min, max}

val df = spark.sqlContext.esDF(esInputIndexName)

val aggDF = df.groupBy("filenames").agg(min("timestamp").as("minDate"), max("timestamp").as("maxDate"))

aggDF.show(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is pretty much what I did until now. Runtime is a pain in the ass though (20min+). This would work a lot faster if the data filtering would happen with the query.